# How to find the last branch checked out in git

Tags: git, git-checkout

We can checkout the last branch using `git checkout -`, but is there a way to just find out what was last branch and not check it out?

EDIT:
I already found that I could use:

```
git reflog | grep -i "checkout: moving"|head -1|cut -d' ' -f6
```

But I wanted to know if there is a direct simpler command. I am updating the question to reflect this need. Sorry about not being clear enough

Comment: some command which may be like 'git branch -' OR 'git -n checkout -' which would give output of the last branch and make no changes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your sample output (as produced by `git reflog | ...`) makes it sufficiently clear.

The `git rev-parse` command can be combined with the reference lookup syntax to do this in one go:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{-1}
refs/heads/stash-exp
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{-1}
stash-exp
```

Note that [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) describes the `@{-N}` syntax.  Note as well that if there is no N'th previous branch, `rev-parse` silently prints nothing at all:

```
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{-2} && echo ok || echo fail
master
ok
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{-3} && echo ok || echo fail
ok
```

And, of course, in most places where you might need the name, you can just use the `@{-1}` syntax directly.

Answer (score 3):

`git reflog` is what you want to use.  In this, you'll find:

- What you've last committed (denoted by "commit")
- What you've checked out (denoted by "checkout")
- When you've pulled  (denoted by "pull")

What you've checked out is important here; the reflog will use a format denoted with "checkout" and specify "moving from A to B" when looking at specific branches.

A simple grep for "checkout: moving" will give you a list of the branches you've visited; the last one is at the top.

Full command for completeness:

```
git reflog | grep -i "checkout: moving"
```

Comment: I already found that I could use: git reflog | grep -i "checkout: moving"|head -1|cut -d' ' -f6. But I wanted to know if there is a direct simpler command. I am updating the question to reflect this need. Sorry about not being clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use grep -m to limit the results:

`git reflog | grep -i “checkout: moving” -m 10`